# Table per hierarchy generic select methods

Tags: asp.net-core, generics, entity-framework-core

I have got a audit logs table, which uses table per hierarchy inheritance. Now I am trying to create repository, which will handle selects from this table. My first idea was to create some generic method which will handle selects for all types. But I cannot figure out how to do it.

My second idea was to create private methods, which will handle select for concrete type and based on generic type, call this private methods in public generic method GetByType. There is another problem, I cannot return concrete type from this method, Visual studio says, it cannot convert to concrete type.

Can you recommend me some best practices in this case?
Is it possible to select concrete types from one generic method? Do I need to create private methods? Is possible to return concrete type from generic method?

**Repository:**

```
 public async Task<PaginatedList<T>> GetByType<T>(AuditLogsQueryFilter queryFilter) where T : Audit
    {
        //idea was to create conditions here and return collections with concrete objects - not working
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(AuditUser))
        {
            var result = await getUserLogs(queryFilter);
            return (PaginatedList<T>) result;
        }

    }

    private async Task<PaginatedList<AuditUser>> GetUserLogs(AuditLogsQueryFilter queryFilter)
    {
        var query = getBaseAuditQuery<AuditUser>();

        query = query.Include(a => a.AffectedUser);

        return await query.ToPaginatedListAsync(queryFilter.Page, queryFilter.PageSize);
    }

    private async Task<PaginatedList<AuditProject>> GetProjectLogs(AuditLogsQueryFilter queryFilter)
    {
        var query = getBaseAuditQuery<AuditProject>();

        query = query.Include(a => a.Project);

        return await query.ToPaginatedListAsync(queryFilter.Page, queryFilter.PageSize);
    }

    private async Task<PaginatedList<AuditAdditionalBlock>> GetAdditionalBlockLogs(AuditLogsQueryFilter queryFilter)
    {
        var query = getBaseAuditQuery<AuditAdditionalBlock>();

        query = query.Include(a => a.AdditionalBlock)
            .ThenInclude(adb => adb.Project);

        return await query.ToPaginatedListAsync(queryFilter.Page, queryFilter.PageSize);
    }

    private async Task<PaginatedList<AuditInvestorRepayments>> GetInvestorRepaymentsLogs(
        AuditLogsQueryFilter queryFilter)
    {
        var query = getBaseAuditQuery<AuditInvestorRepayments>();

        query = query.Include(a => a.Repayment)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.Investment)
            .ThenInclude(i => i.Investor)
            .ThenInclude(i => i.Claims);

        return await query.ToPaginatedListAsync(queryFilter.Page, queryFilter.PageSize);
    }

    private async Task<PaginatedList<AuditDebtorRepayments>> GetDebtorRepaymentsLogs(
        AuditLogsQueryFilter queryFilter)
    {
        var query = getBaseAuditQuery<AuditDebtorRepayments>();

        query = query.Include(a => a.Repayment)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.Project);

        return await query.ToPaginatedListAsync(queryFilter.Page, queryFilter.PageSize);
    }

    private async Task<PaginatedList<AuditCompany>> GetCompaniesLogs(
        AuditLogsQueryFilter queryFilter)
    {
        var query = getBaseAuditQuery<AuditCompany>();

        query = query.Include(a => a.Company);

        return await query.ToPaginatedListAsync(queryFilter.Page, queryFilter.PageSize);
    }

    private async Task<PaginatedList<AuditProjectAccount>> GetProjectAccountsLogs(AuditLogsQueryFilter queryFilter)
    {
        var query = getBaseAuditQuery<AuditProjectAccount>();

        query = query.Include(a => a.ProjectAccount);

        return await query.ToPaginatedListAsync(queryFilter.Page, queryFilter.PageSize);
    }

    private async Task<PaginatedList<AuditBranch>> GetBranchesAudit(AuditLogsQueryFilter queryFilter)
    {
        var query = getBaseAuditQuery<AuditBranch>();

        query = query.Include(a => a.Branche);

        return await query.ToPaginatedListAsync(queryFilter.Page, queryFilter.PageSize);
    }

    private async Task<PaginatedList<AuditInvestment>> GetInvestmentsAudit(AuditLogsQueryFilter queryFilter)
    {
        var query = getBaseAuditQuery<AuditInvestment>();

        query = query.Include(a => a.Investment)
            .ThenInclude(i => i.Investor)
            .ThenInclude(i => i.Claims);

        return await query.ToPaginatedListAsync(queryFilter.Page, queryFilter.PageSize);
    }

    private IQueryable<Audit> filterAuditQuery(IQueryable<Audit> query, AuditLogsQueryFilter queryFilter)
    {
        if (queryFilter.Type != null)
        {
            query = queryFilter.Type != AuditLogsType.User 
                ? query.Where(a => a.TableName == queryFilter.Type.ToString()) 
                : query.Where(a => a.TableName == queryFilter.Type.ToString() || a.TableName == "UserClaim");
        }

        return query;
    }
```

**Entities**:

**BaseClass**:

```
  public class Audit
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public string OldValues { get; set; }
        public string NewValues { get; set; }
        public string AffectedColumns { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryKey { get; set; }
    }
```

**DerivedClasses:**

```
public class AuditUser : Audit
{
    public User AffectedUser { get; set; }
    public string AffectedUserId { get; set; }
}

public class AuditProject : Audit
{
    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

and so on...